# Libreadline cannot be loaded

Tags: php

I cannot make libreadline to work. Server keeps to show

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function readline().

```
CentOS 6
PHP Version 5.4.17

root@myserver#php -i | grep Configure
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curl/' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '**--with-readline**'
--------------------------------------------------------------------

root@myserver#php -m
-------------------------------------------------------------------
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
imap
json
libxml
mysql
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
**readline**
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
timezonedb
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib
```

CLI works, BTW.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your web-based PHP is the same as the command line version. You most likely have MULTIPLE versions installed, and the web-based version is running without readline.

Comment: 5.4.17 for both. but it is activated on cli.